# php mysql simple update: cannot read values

Tags: php, mysql

probably stupid question but...
I have a sample for PHP and MySQL, which doesn't work...
there are 3 php files:

1. list_records.php
2. update.php
3. update_ac.php

the problem is that 3rd one doesn't read variables from the 2nd. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my files/code:

list_records.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>


<td align="center"><a href="update.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Email</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" value="<?php echo $rows['lastname']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

update_ac.php

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="test_mysql"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET name='TEST', lastname='$lastname', email='$email' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: you did not get the values of the post in update query

Comment: For one thing, you have `$id=$_GET['id'];` and using `method="post"` - make them both the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to get the value in the server side from client side before inserting or updating them into the database.for this we have superglobal variables in php like $_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST etc.
so include thses in your update_ac.php:
    `$lastname=$_POST[lastname];`
    `$email=$_POST[email];`
$id=$_POST[id];`

you can use $_REQUEST method if you are not sure by which method u passed the values from the form.but try to avoid it as it is less secure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get them from `POST` in the `update_ac.php` file like

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name 
      SET name='TEST', 
          lastname='".$_POST['lastname']."', 
          email='".$_POST['email']."' 
      WHERE id=".$_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Thanks a million, I thought I was trying that but obviously not. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This  is what you need in your update query

```
......lastname='".$_POST['lastname']."', email='".$_POST['email']."' WHERE id=".$_POST['id']
```

Whenever a `form` posts/submits a value to a file mentioned in an `action`, the file must access the values of form's field's name in `$_POST` array as `$_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email']`. etc. (if the `method` used is `POST` in `form` tag)

There are three ways of access submitted values:

1. GET http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
2. POST http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php
3. REQUEST http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php